# Divide and distribute the result

Tags: python

I'm working on a little project and I would like to know if there is any easy way to do it.

I have a number (4.5), that I would like to equally distribute between X parts (X is a variable number). The tricky part is that the value can be: 0,0.25,0.50,0.75 or 1.

Here an example of a desired output :

```
Number = 4.5

X = 5

result=[1,1,1,0.75,0.75]
```

Is there any easy way to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you try to make use of remainder operators?

Comment: and what if your number can't fit in the result?

Comment: and why is `result=[1,1,1,1,0.5]` not a viable result? Or is it?..

Comment: How can it be equal parts if your answer has 1 and 0.75 ? Explain the question clearly .. is it to divide into X parts with max values from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `itertools` like this:

```py
import itertools 

N = 4.5
parts = 5

arr = [0,.25,.5,.75,1]
for item in itertools.combinations(arr*parts, parts):
    if sum(item) == N:
        print(item)
```

## Update:

Remove duplicated in result:

```py
import itertools 

N = 4.5
parts = 5

res = []

arr = [0,.25,.5,.75,1]
for item in itertools.combinations(arr*parts, parts):
    if sum(item) == N:
       tmp = list(item)
       tmp.sort()
       if tmp not in res:
           res.append(tmp)

print(res)

OUT:
[[0.5, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0.75, 0.75, 1, 1, 1]]
```

Comment: Since these are floating point values, I would not compare for equality, but rather check for a small error e.g. `if abs(sum(item) - N) < 1e-8:`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your valid values are equally spaced and that the given number can always be expressed as a linear combination of those, you can do something like this:

```
def divide_number(number, parts, unit):
    number_units = round(number / unit)
    units_per_part = number_units // parts
    remainder_units = number_units % parts
    return [unit * ((units_per_part + 1) if i < remainder_units else units_per_part)
            for i in range(parts)]

print(divide_number(4.5, 5, 0.25))
# [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.75, 0.75]
```

---

If you want to get all possible combinations using an arbitrary set of split values, you can use a recursive algorithm as follows:

```
def divide_number(number, parts, units, eps=1e-8):
    current = []
    units = sorted(set(units))
    yield from _divide_number_rec(number, parts, units, 0, current, eps)

def _divide_number_rec(number, parts, units, i_unit, current, eps):
    if parts <= 0:
        yield tuple(current)
    else:
        for i in range(i_unit, len(units)):
            unit = units[i]
            if number > unit - eps and number - unit < (parts - 1) * units[-1] + eps:
                current.append(unit)
                yield from _divide_number_rec(number - unit, parts - 1, units, i, current, eps)
                current.pop()

units = [0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1]
# Get one valid combination
print(next(divide_number(4.5, 5, units)))
# (0.5, 1, 1, 1, 1)
# Get all valid combinations
print(*divide_number(4.5, 5, units), sep='\n')
# (0.5, 1, 1, 1, 1)
# (0.75, 0.75, 1, 1, 1)
```

This is in principle less computationally expensive than going through every possible combination, as many of the combinations are pruned when they are not feasible, although for not very big problems there may not be a significant difference.

Comment: Hello, I am in a similar situation as the author of this post, but I would like to remove this limitation of 1 as the maximum number, could you explain me how to do it?
Thanks

Comment: @Thomas The first algorithms do not take into account the limit of 1, but rather assume that the parameters to the function "make sense". Since they distribute the number evenly, the biggest value in the result is always going to be as small as possible (e.g. if you do `divide_number(8.5, 5, 0.25)` there is no way to split it in five parts without numbers greater than 1). If you need the second version (all possible combinations), it would be a different algorithm.

Comment: @Thomas It should probably be a new question (and there is probably some existing very similar answer around), but you can get an algorithm that gives you all possible combinations without limit here https://gist.github.com/javidcf/6c96cd13b3c1895d08c3b2e7d7a12f8b (pass `1` as `min_units` if you want to avoid zeros in the result).

Answer (score 0):

I'll do the assumption that the series shall prefer to avoid small elements, ex if able x.25 will be converted to 1*x-1, .75, .5...

- Asumptions:

  - x >= 1:
    x.25 = [1]*x-1, .75, .50
    x.50 = [1]*x-1, .75, .75
    x.75 = [1]*x-1,   1, .75 = [1]*x, .75 ; Neat to use x-1 for all to establish the pattern
  - 0 <= x < 1:
    return remainder
  - x < 0:
    not valid

---

Code:

```py
from math import modf


def silly_func(number)
    _, discrete = modf(number/.25) # convet to our base
    rem, num    = modf(number/4)   # rem is now 0 or 0.25 or 0.50 or 0.75

    if num > 0:
       loo = [1]*int(num-1) # list of 1s
       if rem == .25:
          return [*loo, .75, .5]
       elif rem == .5:
          return [*loo, .75, .75]
       elif rem == .75:
          return [*loo, 1, .75]
       else:
          return [*loo, 1]
    else:
       return [rem]

    number = 2.34     
    silly_func(number)
```

This is probably not the fastest soulotion buts is easy to understand